# Connecting to CheckPoint VPN with 2FA

Tags: networking, vpn, virtualbox-networking

I'm trying to connect to a CheckPoint VPN which uses two factor authentication (generated token from a mobile device).

I'm aware of the snx tool from CheckPoint, and have used it on other VPNs, but am unable to get it to work with 2FA - or perhaps I just don't know how to use it with 2FA

My question is what are my options, and what's the best option.

- does the snx tool work with 2FA, or is there another CheckPoint client?
- will another client work with a CheckPoint VPN, e.g. StrongSwan, OpenVPN, etc?

I'm working with a plan to run the Windows CheckPoint client in a VM and then route my Ubuntu traffic through the VM's network, but it's clunky at best.

Comment: StrongSwan is a VPN *server* for IPSec and not a VPN client.  OpenVPN has a client and a server but only speaks OpenVPN.  It looks like Checkpoint VPN (CP VPN) under the hood uses a form of IPSec that is tunneled over SSL/TLS.  This might be a unique form of technological deployment.  In pure theory, if CP VPN is speaking IPSec, then you could theoretically build a `vpnc` configuration that would work under the hood, but you're restricted to the CLI version of the VPN client for connecting (2FA isn't usable in the NetworkManager plugin for `vpnc`/IPSec connections). (1/2)

Comment: However, this is a highly speculative answer, as CheckPoint doesn't offer a VPN-only device and only offer it as part of their unified protection gateways, and as CheckPoint gateway solutions are non-free the only people who can really give you clear guidance are going to be the CheckPoint people.  They're pushing *hard* for the SNX tool, though; they don't talk about 2FA though on their forums.  You might want to consult with CheckPoint about 2FA enablement/solutions for things. (2/2)

Comment: It should be possible. I used to have Firefox + java for the web-interface, which just passed stuff to the local snx installation. But I never got my finger around it. Maybe local java debugging could provide some insights.